# What is the difference between async await and a regular fetch?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Can someone please explain to me what the difference between a regular fetch and async await is? I am a beginner so I might get the concepts mixed up but love to get some information so that I can understand more.

Comment: Fetch -> use oldschool callback, async await -> don't

Comment: They are two different things. One (fetch) is an API, that returns a promise. The other (async/await) is a part of the syntax of the JavaScript language and it provides you with one way (not the only way) to handle promises returned from functions or API calls such as fetch.

Comment: What does this have to do with mongodb? Are you not asking about the browser `fetch` http api?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Fetch returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). This means fetch can either be used with promise chaining (using *then*), or with Async/Await. Either way fetch is returning the same result, but how it's handled is different. More on [Async/Await vs then()](https://javascript.info/async-await).